What's the proper way to deploy an app that imports a private package using docker and a CI?
I'm working on two apps: a next.js app, and a react Design System.
The Design System is hosted on a private gitlab registry.
I'm using the Gitlab CI and Docker to deploy my app.
In order to install the Design System, I need to setup my NPM registry. I tried to do so in several ways, but I have doubts regarding the security of my process.
Obviously, I don't want to ship my .npmrc along with my codebase.
Instead, I went for this: I added the following lines in my ci file:

  before_script:
    # Add our GitLab NPM registry information to the .npmrc file
    - echo "@${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/packages/npm/" > .npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/:_authToken=${GITLAB_GROUP_DEPLOY_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc
    - cat .npmrc
    - echo "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login $CONTAINER_REGISTRY -u $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin

Then, the main script runs my docker build command.
In my dockerfile, I added this:
# Setup private NPM registry and install app dependencies
COPY .npmrc ./
RUN cat .npmrc
RUN npm ci

The cat command in the Dockerfile shows plain variables, and I guess it is a bad thing: sensitive informations should not be displayed in the .npmrc at any point.
How am I supposed to pass down the npm config without compromising security ?
